# Quadratic scaling of axes

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale, scaling

The circular arc $$y=\sqrt{1-x^2}\tag{1}$$ becomes the linear function $$y'=1-x'\tag{2}$$ after substitutions $x'=x^2$ and $y'=y^2$. Here I restrict to arguments in the range $[0,1]$. How can I scale the axes so that eq.(1) is displayed as a line. This would be similar to scaling by logarithmic axes.

[image]

```
GraphicsRow[{
Plot[Sqrt[1-x^2],{x,0,1},AspectRatio->1,AxesLabel->{x, y}],
Plot[1-x,{x,0,1},AspectRatio->1,AxesLabel->{x',y'}]
}]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `ScalingFunctions`

```
Plot[Sqrt[1 - x^2], {x, 0, 1}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {{Re[#^2] &, Re@Sqrt[#] &}, {Re[#^2] &, 
    Re@Sqrt[#] &}}, Ticks -> {0, 1}]
```

[image]

You can play with the Ticks to obtain values in `x'` and '`y'`.

Comment: e.g. `Ticks -> {Round[Table[Sqrt[i], {i, 0, 1, 0.1}], 0.01]}` provides evenly spaced (but rounded) tick marks.

Comment: Could you say more in the answer to {Re[#^2] &, Re@Sqrt[#] &} ?

Comment: `ScalingFunction` requires a function and its inverse, hence #^2 and Sqrt[#]. The `Re` is leftover from when I was debugging and isn't needed.